# How to kill logcat process initiated by Android application?

Tags: android, process

I have Android application that on Service start implement followed code:

```
...
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -s " + arg);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
...
```

As you see I start logcat process to listen on logs.
Unfortunately, the stop service doesn't stop logcat and after several launches i get:

```
app_125   4782  144   137124 30584 ffffffff 00000000 S com.wefi.agnt.ui
app_125   4796  4782  1028   592   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
app_125   4839  4782  1076   640   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
app_125   4842  4782  952    516   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
app_125   4845  4782  896    460   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
app_125   4848  4782  900    464   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
app_125   4851  4782  876    440   ffffffff 00000000 S logcat
shell     4852  171   788    336   c00cc7e4 afd0c78c S /system/bin/sh
shell     4853  4852  944    332   00000000 afd0b83c R ps
app_123   11189 144   114484 18908 ffffffff 00000000 S com.mspot.android.moviesClub.att
```

... list of logcat processes. How can I kill them?

Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a handle on the `Process` instance, you should be able to use `process.destroy()` when you stop your service. The Logcat processes are running independently of your app, so they will continue running after your app's `Service` stops running unless you terminate them.

If you just want to clean up the processes on your device while testing the app, you can run `adb shell` to get a shell prompt on the device, and then use `kill <PID>` to terminate a process.

**EDIT**:

The `Process` documentation also specifies that you should use `ProcessBuilder` to set up and run the process:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("logcat", "-v", "time", "-s", arg);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
...
```

Comment: This is a problem, my device is not rooted I can't kill the process with `kill` command, doesn't have permissions

Comment: `process.destry()` doesn't work as well, it tells me that killed successfully but process still running. I thought about scenario where I check if logcat runs and after try to use it instead to build new one

Comment: That problem may be related to the way that you're starting the process. Please take a look at the [documentation for Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html); specifically, the code snippet given in the overview that uses `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks @acj, I found solution that works with your help.                 ` ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("logcat", "-v", "time", "-s", arg);
         pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process logcatProcess = pb.start();                                ...`

Comment: Maxim, how did ProcessBuilder help you? I have the same problem as you do - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173387/android-child-process-logcat-keeps-running-after-parent-process-app-died - and using ProcessBuilder was no solution in my case, logcat just keeps running.

Comment: This worked fine for me, Created a Process and then when adb is required to finish off, I called process.destroy(). You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

First for starting adb logging, create a process as:

```
 String cmd1 = "logcat -v time -f" + filename.getAbsolutePath();
 Process logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
```

After this, whenever you want to stop adb updates to write on file, simplily call:

```
 String cmd = "logcat -c";
    try {
        logcat.destroy();
        logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will destroy the previous build Process and clear all the previously recorded adb logs. So, the time you start adb logging again, it will start from the same time, without adding a repeated values from previous log.